# Ensure that a variable is only set once

Tags: java, exception, thread-safety

I need to ensure that an article is only sold once.
This must be ensured over several threads as well.

Is it enough to check if the `buyer` variable is not null? So in my opinion, the second caller will receive an `AlreadyBoughtException`?

```
public synchronized void buy(Buyer buyer) throws AlreadyBoughtException {
    if (this.buyer != null) {
        throw new AlreadyBoughtException();
    }

    System.out.println(buyer + " bought article " + identifier);

    this.buyer = buyer;
    this.sold = true;
}
```

Is this thread-safe and can I assume that there is no chance that the article cannot be bought when the `buy` method is called at the same time (exactly the same time)?

Comment: Your code is correct, but with AtomicRefference you can achieve a better performance and less thread contention.

Comment: I would check `this.sold == true`. I don't understand why to complicate with the buyer.

Comment: Just an example, tried something else aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that your method is synchronized does make it safe - so long as this is the only way you ever update the buyer.

Answer (score 5):

As long as `buyer` can not be set via a non-synchronized method, your code is threadsafe.

The JVM will ensure that "exactly the same time" never happens for a synchronized method - one caller will be deemed to be first, and the other will have to wait until the first call has completed before proceeding.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is fine (unless of course you're accessing the buyer field from another method).

Two threads trying to execute this method at the same time won't be able to do so: only one will be able to get the lock and will initialize the buyer. The other thread will then execute it, and see the initialized buyer since the method is synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

You can have

```
this.buyer
```

volatile variable

Comment: Makes it sense to do both? Synchronized setter and using volatile?

Comment: No, volatile is not needed if you are also synchronized as synchronized does everything volatile does and more. Volatile also will not be enough here as you would have several race conditions, it would actually be dangerous to have volatile but not synchronized.

Comment: @Tim B I agree with you, synchronized is not needed if volatile is used (that's what I meant by answer) . But there wont be any race condition as volatile variable is been accessed in the second line of function. And memory barriers will make the most update value of this.buyer available to threads.

Comment: You are completely wrong. Synchronized IS needed. Otherwise two threads can both check that `buyer` is null, go past the check and then both write the new value into `buyer`...allowing the item to be sold twice.

Comment: Agreed. as its setting the value in buyer later which might get other threads to come forward and go ahead in race.